# Format of query/question on answers.ros.org

Tags: ros, answers.ros.org

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello again,
It is possible to escape (or somehow pre-process) non-alphanumeric data before using it for searches?

For example you were searching for questions related to the topic [/camera/image_raw](http://answers.ros.org/questions/scope:all/sort:activity-desc/query:%2Fcamera%2Fimage_raw/page:1/) the "page not found" error would appear.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/29486/format-of-query/question-on-answers.ros.org/) by [SL Remy](https://answers.ros.org/users/1001/sl-remy/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2022 on 2012-03-10

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There's not a solution at the moment.  Ticketed: https://code.ros.org/trac/ros/ticket/3887

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2012-03-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0